# Grunt Plugin to keep version in readme.md up to date

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, version, grunt-plugins

I user grunt-bumper to bump up my version in the package.json file if I release my app. I have a readme.md file included as well in which the current version is also described. I am no searching for a way that grunt updates this version tag automatically each time, I release my app.

I neither have found a plugin for this nor did I find an easy way to get this to work manually..

Does anybody have a clue how this can be done easily`and nice?

Comment: Interested too! Now I generate README.md from Handlebars template :) But two files for readme isn't much cool.

Comment: currently I am thinking about doing a simple string replace, but this is just one quick/dirty hack I think.